# How to make a search box like this one?

Tags: html, search-box

I want to create a search box like this one. Can anybody help me?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 input placeholder attribute:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

For the image of the search icon check out this:
[search icon inside search box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670865/search-icon-inside-search-box)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```